# R How to use a complex function at seasonal period under hydroTSM and xts packages?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, apply, xts

I want to calculate the seasonal mean of my parameter values (when `x > 0.002`). To do this, I use `xts::period.apply()` to separate the values seasonally. I use the "quarter" period in `endpoints()`, but the "quarter" period divides the year under four seasons as following:

```
"January+February+March", 
"April+May+June", 
"July+August+Septembre",
"October+November+December"
```

For example:

```
library(xts) 
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

data(edhec) 
head(edhec)

edhec_4yr <- edhec["1997/2001"] 
ep <- endpoints(edhec_4yr, "quarter")
# mean 
period.apply(edhec_4yr, INDEX = ep,
  function(x) apply(x,2, function(y) mean(y[y>0.002])))
```

But for my study, I want my seasonal period divided as following:

```
"December+January+February", 
"March+April+May", 
"June+July+August", 
"Septembre+October+November"
```

Can you help me how to change the order months of "quarter" period?

I can use the simple function (`mean`, `max`, `min`) under the hydroTSM package with the following function:

```
dm2seasonal(edhec_4yr, FUN=mean, season="DJF")
```

Where:

```
 DJF : December, January, February
 MAM : March, April, May
 JJA : June, July, August
 SON : September, October, November
```

But I cannot applied the complex function (mean with condition) as the following function:

```
dm2seasonal(edhec_4yr, season="DJF",
  function(x) apply(x,2, function(y) mean(y[y>0.002])))
```

Can you help me how to improve this function in order to calculate mean value (when `x > 0.02`) for DJF for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xts::endpoints()` function always returns the last observation in a "standard" period, starting from the origin (midnight, 1970-01-01). So it can't easily do what you want.

You can calculate your own period end points by finding the observation on the last day of the last month in each 3-month window.  Here's one way to do that with monthly data:

```
# .indexmon() returns a zero-based month
ep <- which((.indexmon(edhec_4yr) + 1) %in% c(2, 5, 8, 11))
aggfn <- function(x, bound = 0.002, ...) {
  apply(x,2, function(y) mean(y[y > bound], ...))
}
period.apply(edhec_4yr, ep, aggfn)
```

If you have daily data, you need to find the last day of each month your periods end in. You can do that by using `.indexmon()` to find all months that end each season, then construct an xts object with the locations of all those observations in the original daily data object. Then you can use `apply.monthly()` and `last()` to extract the location of the last day of each season-ending month. The resulting object contains the end points you need to pass to `period.apply()`.

```
data(prices)
prices <- as.xts(prices)  # 'prices' is zoo; convert to xts
season_months <- (.indexmon(prices)+1) %in% c(2, 5, 8, 11)
ep_months <- xts(which(season_months), index(prices)[season_months])
ep_seasons <- as.numeric(apply.monthly(ep_months, last))
period.apply(prices, ep_seasons, aggfn)
```

And I should note that I'm thinking about how to specify end points in a more flexible manner, and I'll make sure to include a way to specify seasons.

Comment: Thank you very mauch Joshua Ulrich. Thank you very much for the time you bring to my problematic! thank you for these detailed solutions!It's impressive!